# Cell to relate to information depending on infrmation in another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I hope you can understand what I mean. I have tried to draw below to help explain.

I need column d to have the information in column a1 and column h to have the information in a2- Keeping it in the same row. This all relates to the information in column b? I have hundreds of figures and I have coded them all in column b but now need to get the figures to go into the columns I need them to.

```
  a  b  c  d  f  g  h  I  j  k  l
1 50 D
2 20 W
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather, you need to do the following:

Go to D1 and type =A1 (this will set the value equal to A1), then drag the small black box in the bottom right corner down as far as you need (this will change the following values to =A2, =A3, =A4, and so on)
Do the same for column H but use B1 instead of A1.

Is this what you were looking to do?